# What does the mkswap command do?

Tags: 16.04, partitioning, swap, disk, system

I know what this command does. It sets up swap area on a device or in a file.
The device being a partition, and file being a simple file.

But I want to know what it does internally on the disk.

Correct me here if I am wrong, **Swap is slower than RAM, but faster than simple Disk for operations.**

This is my question.

What changes does `mkswap` makes on disk? I mean, the swap area is still on disk (be it a partition or a file), right?, then how come it works faster than rest of the disk? It must be doing some changes on the disk? What are these changes?

EDIT - It is in reference to this video, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uxiis-K6v7w

here it is being told that data accessed frequently is moved to the outer area of the disk. So, I guess `mkswap` might move the swap partition/file to some outer area of the disk.

Comment: I _strongly_ disagree that this is a duplicate.  I know what Swap Space is, but that doesn't tell me what `mkswap` does to a logical file or physical partition except maybe, as the question states, moves it's logical allocation to a contiguous place on the physical disk.  @Ravexina links to a question whose accepted answer also properly answers this question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/846163/does-swap-space-have-a-filesystem ... even though the question isn't about `mkswap` it does a great job of explaining what `mkswap` actually does.  The `answer here` link above does not.

Answer (score 6):

Swap is not faster than of your disk, think about it in form of manufacture, how can your car becomes faster without any tuning of its physical parts?

`mkswap` is **somehow** like other `mkfs` utilities, it prepares your file or partition to be used as a swapping space in a special form which it can't be thought of any other kind of file systems. it prepares a portion of your disk which might be upon a file system itself (a swap file) to save the memory pages directly into it. That might be the reason of feeling it being a little bit more faster.

Also it's nice to read: [Does swap space have a filesystem?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/846163/does-swap-space-have-a-filesystem)

Comment: I have added more info about the question. check it

Comment: I didn't see the video, however I can guess that it meant to be "data accessed frequently is moved to the outer area of the swap" just like a stack, if you're using a file as a swap space it will be where ever it was created, same as a partition which you can't change it's physical location on disk using `mkswap`.

Answer (score 0):

`mkswap` does not make your disk faster. When your swap space resides on a disk it is bound to the physical constraints of that disk. There is no magic that would speed up a physical disk.

Compared to a standard filesystem like *ext4* or *xfs* it might be faster as the management overhead and disk placement is much simpler.

Comment: I have added more info about the question. check it